# Did most people self-identify as Bulgarians in first census of Macedonia?

Tags: history

I remember seeing on TV in my own country (Bulgaria) floated the claim that during the first census done in Macedonia, most of the population was self-identifying as Bulgarians.

After that, the story goes, the Serbian authorities (Macedonia had been given under the control of Serbia), annulled the census, much violence ensued, and a second census was done, and none claimed to be Bulgarians.

Since, my own country is a bit biased on the subject, I'm asking here if anyone can verify this claim - did such a thing happen during the first census, or any census.

If the story is true, may be there won't be direct evidence, since the authorities would have destroyed evidence of the first census, but some historical traces would have been left.

Comment: Can you point to the claim somewhere, published online perhaps? I'm not doubting the claim is notable, but I think seeing the specifics of the claim, and those who made it, etc, might help in finding an answer.

Comment: @Flimzy I will try searching for it online, but otherwise, I've seen the claim on bulgarian-language TV only. I think (but I'm not sure) it was made by Bulgarian historian [Bozhidar Dimitrov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bozhidar_Dimitrov) in his popular TV show.